# Classic ASP calling WCF Service

Tags: xml, wcf, asp-classic

I am calling a WCF service from a legacy app. I have the below code:

```
serviceUrl = "https://link.to/Services/MyService.svc" 
Dim oXmlHTTP : Set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
oXmlHTTP.setOption 2, 13056
oXmlHTTP.Open "POST", serviceUrl, False 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(SOAPRequest)
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "InsertPerson" 
oXmlHTTP.send(SOAPRequest)
writetologfile(oXmlHTTP.responseXML.xml) 
Dim responseStatus
responseStatus = oXmlHTTP.responseText
writetologfile(responseStatus)
writetologfile(oXmlHTTP.responseBody)
```

SOAPRequest is my XML which is formed correctly

writetologfile is a self explanatory method that, shockingly, writes to a log file.

The issue is that the above code doesn't seemingly call the service at all. The oXmlHTTP.Response objects are null and I can't track down what the issue is. The code doesn't appear to error as if the call has worked correctly, but it seemingly isn't (or if it is, the response isn't being set).

Any thoughts?

Edit: I assume it's oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "InsertPerson" that is causing the issue? How can I work out what the SOAPAction value should be? Is this a namespace on the Method I am trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my SOAP Envelope was massively incorrect. Debugging the classic asp (after changing IIS setting_ led me to this.